# Stale element reference when trying to Automate Microsoft Login with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to implement a class in Selenium C# to handle the Microsoft Login for a certaing page. I have two pagination classes where i get the elements for the first and the second stages of the login. Then i have a class where i get the data in there using a json parser declared in the global class.

Currently the Class code for the login looks like this:

```
    public class MenuTest : GlobalClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void Inicio()
        {
            LoginPage primera = new LoginPage(driver.Value);
            primera.getEmailBox().SendKeys(getDataParser().Extractdata("email"));
            primera.getNext().Click();
            LoginPageB segunda = new LoginPageB(driver.Value);
            segunda.getPassBox().SendKeys(getDataParser().Extractdata("password"));
            segunda.getSignIn().Click();
        }
    }
```

This works great until it gets to the SignIn button where i get this error code:

Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception

Stack Trace: 
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) WebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)

I have tried, throwing waits before the SignIn button use after the password insert, i've tried implementing the findby on the script itself. I've also tried using try/Catch dynamic to find it again after the error. Everything failed

LoginPage A and LoginPage B are implemented like this:

````
{
    public class LoginPageB
    {

        private IWebDriver driver;

        public LoginPageB(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);            
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "passwd")]     
        private IWebElement Password;
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='idSIButton9']")]
        private IWebElement SignIn;


        public IWebElement getPassBox()
        {
            return Password;
        }
        public IWebElement getSignIn()
        {            
            return SignIn;
        }
    }
}```



public class LoginPage : GlobalClass
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        waitforelement(driver, "//*[@id=\"i0116\"]");
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        //Esto revisa todos los FindsBy y los iniciaza 

    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "loginfmt")]
    //Esta variable esta privada
    private IWebElement Emailfield;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "idSIButton9")]
    private IWebElement Siguiente;



    //Esto encapsula el valor que se inicio de forma privada. 
    public IWebElement getEmailBox()
    {
        return Emailfield;
    }
    public IWebElement getNext()
    {
        return Siguiente;
    }

}
````

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. For some reason I couldn't figure out, trying to insert `waits` like this: `waitforelement(driver.Value, "//input[@id='idSIButton9']` or this
`driver.Value.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` wasn't effective at all.

But finally using `Thread.sleep(1000)` between the click on the next button and the initialization of the `loadpageB` object solved it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as others, the only thing that helped me was the sleep.

I had tried things like:

```
WebElement SignInButton = DriverContext.Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
DriverContext.waitForElement(SignInButton);
```

changing the xpath (as i had used the same for Next button in username step):

```
WebElement SignInButton = DriverContext.Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign in']"));
```

also tried a try/catch:

```
try {
    SignInButton.click();
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException e){ }
```

I only got it to work using the sleep:

```
DriverContext.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: I had some success using the  following format:

 WebDriverWait newwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));

newwait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(locator)))

This did the trick for me, although i still have to find a way that lets me avid using locators inside the file where i call the wait.